# How to print the full content of an overflowing iframe?

Tags: php, html, css

I created a tool to be used on multiple website. They all open it in a iFrame. (I have no control over this)

I have been asked to add a "print" button.

The issue is, when I try to print, it print the iframe content, but only what is currently shown. The iframe content is overflowing verticaly, so I'm missing half the content. The print will only show what is currently visible.

As I have 0 control over the iframe itself, is there a way for me to print the full iframe content?

I thought about opening a new window, but they don't want the users to see the url of my tool.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style >
      .iframe_print {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        border: 0;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="https://alkegen.com/"
      class="iframe_print"
    >
  </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is an example of the issue. It is not my tool, I took a random webpage that let me connect to it in iframe. Can't show it in codepen because the issue isn't clear with the 4 windows of codepen.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you printing just the iframe content, or are you printing the parent page with the iframe content somewhere in it?

Comment: I want to prend the iframe content only. He does work, but it only print the "visible" part of the iframe (50% of it is hidden because of overflow)

Comment: So your button just calls `window.print()` then? Wasn't aware that in an iframe context, that would behave differently than in a "top window", regarding overflow. The iframe itself is allowed to scroll its content though, yes? That is not hidden on the screen already, scrollbars disabled or something?

Comment: _"I thought about opening a new window, but they don't want the users to see the url of my tool."_ - maybe if you created another iframe inside your iframe (dynamically), that loads the same document again, but is high enough to contain all of it - and then explicitly called `print()` on that second one ...? You could position it outside of the viewport of the first iframe, so that the user doesn't see it.

Comment: @cBroe

I would have to test, but I suspect I won't be able to print more, as my first iframe is too small. I added code example.

Also right now, I'm only using the print shortcut in the browser, not calling window.print().

Comment: _"I'm only using the print shortcut in the browser"_ - but specifically for your iframe, and not for the whole parent page, right?

Comment: Yes, it only print my iframe content.